# Atualização de status baseado no saldo

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angularjs-directives

Eu estou desenvolvendo um projeto com typescript e não estou conseguindo usar js nele.

este projeto tem varias rotinas, e na maioria delas tem essa questão de status, se esta aberta, fechada ou bloqueada

projeto abaixo

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

ele esta muito manual, tendo que ser trocado o estoque, pelo o próprio usuário

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { NbDialogService } from '@nebular/theme';
import { Entradaestoque } from '../../../@core/data/miscellaneous/entradaestoque.model';
import { EntradaestoqueService } from '../../../@core/mock/miscellaneous/entradaestoque.service';
import { EntradaestoqueBlockComponent } from './entradaestoque-block.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'ngx-entradaestoque',
  template:` 
   <nb-card>
    <nb-card-header>Entrada Estoque</nb-card-header>
    <nb-card-body>
    <table style="min-width:1000px; width: 100%;" mat-table class="content-table" matSort aria-label="Elements" [dataSource]="entradaestoque">
  
  <!-- Status Coluna -->
 <ng-container matColumnDef="status">
   <th class="thead"  mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef></th>
   <td class="tbody"  mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
   <i id='status' [style.color]="(ent_qtde <= 10) ? 'red' : '#0dd50d'" class="material-icons">radio_button_checked</i></td>
 </ng-container>

 <!-- Name Coluna -->
 <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
   <th class="thead"  mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Produto:</th>
   <td class="tbody"  mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.ent_name | uppercase}}</td>
 </ng-container>

 <!-- Estado Coluna -->

 <ng-container matColumnDef="fornecedor">
   <th class="thead"  mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Fornecedor:</th>
   <td class="tbody"  mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.ent_fornecedor | uppercase}}</td>
 </ng-container>

 <!-- E-mail Coluna -->

 <ng-container matColumnDef="qtde">
   <th class="thead"  mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Saldo Estoque:</th>
 <td class="tbody" #saldo id="saldo" mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.ent_qtde | uppercase}}</td>
 </ng-container>
 
 <!-- CPF Coluna -->

 <ng-container matColumnDef="sku">
   <th class="thead"  mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>SKU:</th>
 <td class="tbody"    mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.ent_sku | uppercase}}</td>
 </ng-container>




 <!-- Vizualizar Coluna --> 


 <ng-container matColumnDef="açôes">
   <th class="thead"  mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Açôes</th>
 <td class="tbody"  mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
   <a routerLink="vizualizar/{{row.id}}" class="visually">
     <i class="material-icons">visibility</i>
   </a>
   <a routerLink="atualizar/{{ row.id }}"  class="edit" >
     <i class="material-icons">edit</i>
   </a>
   <a routerLink="block/{{ row.id }}"  class="edit" >
     <i class="material-icons">more_vert</i>
   </a>
 </td>
 </ng-container>
 

 
 <tr class="tbody"  mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
 <tr class="tbody"  mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>


 

</table>

<div id="tes">
  
</div>
</nb-card-body>
<button class="create" routerLink="create">Incluir</button>
  </nb-card>
`,
styleUrls: ['entradaestoque-style.component.scss']
})
export class EntradaestoqueComponent implements OnInit {
  

  entradaestoque!: Entradaestoque[];
  displayedColumns = ['status','name', 'fornecedor', 'qtde','sku', 'açôes'];
  dropdownService: any;

  @ViewChild('test') test: HTMLElement;

constructor( private router: Router, private entradaestoqueService: EntradaestoqueService, private dialogService: NbDialogService) {
  
 }
 


ngOnInit(): void {
  console.log(this.test)
  this.entradaestoqueService.read().subscribe(entradaestoque => {
    this.entradaestoque = entradaestoque
    console.log(entradaestoque)
  })
}



navigateToEntradaestoqueCreate(): void {
  this.router.navigate(['client/create'])
}


}
```

abaixo está o código fonte da table,(sim, eu estou usando html no próprio typescript)

então eu pensei que usando Diretivas: ngStyle do angular poderia funcionar.

na linha 16 - 22

```
  <!-- Status Coluna -->
 <ng-container matColumnDef="status">
   <th class="thead"  mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef></th>
   <td class="tbody"  mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
   <i id='status' [style.color]="(ent_qtde <= 10) ? 'red' : '#0dd50d'" class="material-icons">radio_button_checked</i></td>
 </ng-container>
```

o ent_qtde recebe a quantidade de produtos em estoque, direto do banco
só que teoricamente essa diretiva iria mudar a cor caso fosse 'true' ou 'false'

só que ela sempre fica no 'true' = 'green'

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 0):

Você pode adicionar uma classe baseado no valor de uma variável da seguinte forma:

```
<div [class.collapse]="isCollapsed"></div>
```

Caso o valor da variável isCollapsed seja verdadeiro, a classe collapse será aplicada a div.
Assim você pode criar uma classe com as cores que deseja aplicar.

Uma dica que dou é separar o arquivo html do seu arquivo ts, fica mais fácil de ler e organizar o código.

A notação para o template é da seguinte maneira:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-user-card',
  templateUrl: './user-card.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user-card.component.scss']
})
```

Este é um exemplo de um componente que tenho em um projeto meu.